# File is always named with the Path

Tags: c#, file, visual-studio-2012, path, filestream

My File is always named like the path and my additional informations i want to have in the Filename but why is it like that?

The Path should be the chosen folder and i want to create a folder then, how can i add a folder than and say + that folder path?
The file is also always created 1 layer above the one i want. For example: C:\Test but the file is saved then in C:\ instead of C:\Test.

```
public static string path= string.Empty;        

string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + "test.txt";

try
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path + fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(fs);

    sw.WriteLine("Test and so on ..");
}
catch(Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to be in `c:\test` when you not specify a path?  And what does *chosen folder* mean, because I don't see any way to choose a folder.

Comment: File will be saved in the root since you do not specify a path/

Comment: The path is in the working directory, but it doesn't really matter it was just a example. Change the path works but the filename and the path is a problem, because the path is always one layer above the one i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using string concatenation, use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Aside from anything else, that will be portable if you ever want to use Mono, too.

Oh, and there are simpler ways to create a text file too:

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(path, fileName))
{
    writer.WriteLine(...);
}
```

Finally, I'd strongly advise using `-` instead of `.` in your filename, so that anything which looks at the *first* `.` and expects the rest to be an extension doesn't get confused:

```
string fileName = DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "-test.txt";
```

Comment: and how can i fix the bug with using the filestream. I've had several problems using File like the file is still used and so on. And how could i add a created folder to the path?

Comment: @user3438236: "the bug"? You haven't described a bug. But I note that you're not using a `using` statement for either your stream or your writer (unlike my code) which means you're not closing them...

Comment: I've closed the filstream and the streamwriter later, because there is a lot of things that i write into the txt. file

Comment: @user3438236: Well then your code isn't as presented - the variables are out of scope at the end of the block. I can't tell what's wrong with code that you haven't shown us - but I'd *strongly* recommend that you use `using` statements. If you still have other problems, ask a new question.